# How to change SpatRast resolution using res and projectRaster in library(terra) correctly?

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf, cdo-climate, terra

I have a raster file of sea surface temperatures from HadISST at 1x1 resolution. Previously I've re-grid to 0.5 x 0.5 using `cdo(csl("remapbil","global_0.5"), inputfile, output file, debug=FALSE)` from `cdo` via `climateoperators` but I'd like to explore how the workflow would be in `terra` using `projectRaster`. Example below using a HadISST nc file and `rnaturalearth`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyterra)
library(terra)
library(tmaptools)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)

### HadISST SST ndcf file (518kb)
if (!file.exists("HadISST_SST.nc.gz")) { 
     download.file("https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadisst/data/HadISST1_SST_update.nc.gz","HadISST_SST.nc.gz")
     R.utils:::gunzip("HadISST_SST.nc.gz")
}

hadISST <- terra::rast('HadISST_SST.nc') 
hadISST_mean <- mean(hadISST) %>% clamp(lower=5, value=5)
hadISST_outlines <- mean(hadISST) %>% as.polygons(dissolve=FALSE)

### natural earth world coastline
worldrn_m <- ne_coastline(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf") %>%  st_transform(crs = st_crs(hadISST))

ggplot() + theme_bw() + coord_fixed() + xlim(90,150) +  ylim(-20,40) + 
  geom_spatraster(data=hadISST_mean,  alpha=0.8) +
  geom_spatvector(data=hadISST_outlines, color="black", size=0.1, fill=NA,  alpha=0.5) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "viridis", limits=c(0, 35), breaks=seq(5,35,by=5)) +
  geom_sf(data=worldrn_m)
```

[image]

projectRaster failed without a CRS using the following:

```
test <- projectRaster(hadISST_mean, res = 0.5, method="bilinear")

Error in rgdal::checkCRSArgs_ng(uprojargs = uprojargs, SRS_string = SRS_string,  : 
  is.character(SRS_string) is not TRUE
```

the crs I've used with sf previously throws the same error:

```
target_crs <- st_crs("+proj=longlat +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=180")
test <- projectRaster(hadISST_mean, res = 0.5, crs=target_crs, method="bilinear")

Error in rgdal::checkCRSArgs_ng(uprojargs = uprojargs, SRS_string = SRS_string,  : 
  is.character(SRS_string) is not TRUE
```

Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `projectRaster` method for a `<SpatRaster>`. You can use `terra::project` instead, either by providing a character representation of a coordinate reference system (see below), or (much better) by providing a raster template (see `?terra::project`).

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
pr <- project(r, "EPSG:2169", res=100)
```

And for a SpatVector

```
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
pv <- project(v, crs(pr))

plot(pr); lines(pv)
```

But if your goal is to change the *resolution* (as opposed to the *coordinate reference system*) `project` is not the appropriate method, and you should use `disaggregate` or `resample` instead. For example:

```
rr <- disagg(r, 2)
```

When asking questions, try to use a minimal, self-contained, example, as I show above; without loading unnecessary packages (never use `library(tidyverse)` to avoid asking us to install many packages, none of them relevant to the question at hand). Here is a reduced form of your example

```
library(terra)
library(geodata)
w <- geodata::world(path=".")
h <- rast(res=1) |> init("col") |> mask(w)
crs <- "+proj=longlat +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=180"
test <- project(h, crs, res=0.5, method="bilinear")
```

I do not know why, but the projection is not working properly (nothing changes). The below does shift the location of the cropped area, but the values are gone.

```
hcrop <- crop(h, ext(90,150,-20,40)) 
test2 <- project(hcrop, crs, res=0.5, method="bilinear")
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 120, 120, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
#extent      : -90, -30, -20, 40  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=180 
#source      : memory 
#name        : lyr.1 
#min value   :   NaN 
#max value   :   NaN
```

The good news is that it seems that a better way to achieve what you are after goes like this:

```
x <- rotate(h, FALSE)
```

And you can change the resolution with:

```
y <- disagg(x, 2, method="bilinear")
plot(y)
```